# Exclude specific node in TORQUE qsub request

Tags: pbs, qsub, torque

The cluster in my campus uses PBS TORQUE for job management.

There are a couple of nodes that are out of date in software. If my job gets sent to one of those nodes, it will fail. Is there a way to exclude a specific node (or list of nodes) in a job request?

Comment: You can specify a specific node or a list of nodes you want to run on but that would be very limiting. I would ask the admin to assign a property to the nodes that are up to date and then you can request a subset of the nodes with that property. You can find the syntax here: http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/4-1-3/Content/topics/2-jobs/requestingRes.htm

Comment: @chuck The admins are very busy with other stuff and take way too long to respond, and usually just don't pay attention to things like these. How can I specify a list of *alternative* nodes where my job can run?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can specify a set that your job can choose from. You can specify a list of nodes but you will have to wait for all of them to become free before your job will run. Depending on the number of nodes you need to exclude you can do something like this.

`cat $PBS_NODEFILE | grep -v badnode1 |grep -v badnode2 > goodnodes
NP=wc -l goodnodes #need back ticks around "wc -l goodnodes"
mpirun -np $NP -machinefile goodnodes ./a.out`

This isn't ideal if you are in any way charged for resources but it should help you get your jobs run.